# Html button click event detection in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

hi i am getting successfully html button click event in android webview side.its work fine when my html file inside android asset folder but when i have used html page online url it's say Android keywords not found in Javascript code. here's my code

```
//webview android addJavascriptInterface
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android"); 
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getViewId(String result) {
        Log.d("Sid", "click-----------" + result);
    }
}
```

my html and js code

```
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="saveId('122');">1</button>
    <button onClick="saveId('222');">2</button>
    <img onclick="saveId('imgClickEvent')" src="file:///android_res/drawable/dtech.png"/>
</body>
```

```
<script language="javascript">

  function saveId(_id){
 //Android keyword not found how to solve it ?
    Android.getViewId(_id);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution for above my question. Android (Android.getViewId(_id)) keyword only work on when your javascript inside in html page not external js file.